# Why is Quarkus Bootstrap failing?

Tags: aws-lambda, quarkus

I have an app I've built using Quarkus, and I'm trying to trigger it using AWS Lambda. Here is the log I receive when I test the lambda:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Quarkus bootstrap failed.\njava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl. Current classpath: file:/var/task/\n\tat lambdainternal.CustomerClassLoader.findClass(CustomerClassLoader.java:63)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)\n\tat io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler.<clinit>(QuarkusStreamHandler.java:30)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)\n\tat lambdainternal.HandlerInfo.fromString(HandlerInfo.java:33)\n\tat lambdainternal.AWSLambda.findUserMethods(AWSLambda.java:108)\n\tat lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:226)\n\tat lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:195)\n\tat lambdainternal.AWSLambda.main(AWSLambda.java:189)\n",
  "errorType": "java.io.IOException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler.handleRequest(QuarkusStreamHandler.java:56)",
    "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
    "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)",
    "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)",
    "java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"
  ]
}
```

that error message is:

```
% pbpaste | jq -r
Quarkus bootstrap failed.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl. Current classpath: file:/var/task/
    at lambdainternal.CustomerClassLoader.findClass(CustomerClassLoader.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler.<clinit>(QuarkusStreamHandler.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at lambdainternal.HandlerInfo.fromString(HandlerInfo.java:33)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.findUserMethods(AWSLambda.java:108)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:226)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:195)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.main(AWSLambda.java:189)
```

Here is the lambda function handler:

```
public class LambdaSolver implements RequestStreamHandler{

    private static final long PROBLEM_ID = 0L;

    private final AtomicReference<Throwable> solverError = new AtomicReference<>();
    private static final AtomicLong sequence = new AtomicLong();
   
    @Inject
    ScoreManager<VehicleRoutingSolution, HardSoftLongScore> scoreManager;
    @Inject 
    VehicleRoutingSolutionRepository repository;
    @Inject
    SolverManager<VehicleRoutingSolution, Long> solverManager;
    
    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
     
        int letter;
        while ((letter = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            int character = Character.toUpperCase(letter);
            outputStream.write(character);
        }
        
        
        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: I'm not a Java person, but this looks like it's thes ame thing you're seeing https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/7949

Comment: What version of Quarkus are you using?

Comment: @geoand I am using version 2.1

Comment: Can you try Quarkus `2.4.1.Final` please?

Comment: Tried this, seeing the same issue.